# In Aerospike, touch operation with ttl specified in ops using C client is not resetting to specified value. it reset to default config value

Tags: c, aerospike

```
as_status update_record_ttl(int ttl, const char *key) {
        as_operations ops;
        as_operations_inita(&ops, 1);
        as_operations_add_touch(&ops);

        ops.ttl = ttl;
        as_error err;
        as_key record_key;
        as_key_init_str(&record_key, g_namespace, g_set, key);
        if (aerospike_key_operate(&g_as, &err, NULL, &g_key, &ops, NULL) !=
                        AEROSPIKE_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "TTL update failed!! rc=%d\n", err.code);
        }
       as_operations_destroy(&ops);
       return err.code;
}
```

Above code is meant to reset the ttl with specified value but it is only resetting it default config ttl. I want to set the ttl with different value other then default config. Can  anyone help with it.

Thanks

Comment: I am using Aerospike client version 5.2.1.

Comment: What is your default ttl for the namespace and what are you setting it to in the function?

Comment: Default TTl is 30D and i am resetting it to 300 Sec, after debugging i discovered that after touch operation it is setting ttl to 300s but after performing other operation. it is again resetting it to default ttl. Specifically i am doing map remove operation i.e as_operations_add_map_remove_by_value_range after touch operation.

Comment: In general, reducing a record's ttl, from the client, below its current remaining life on the server, is a recipe for trouble. Not recommended.

Comment: As per requirement, I wanted to have different ttl for each record and I have to do with operate operation. I able to do that by setting ops.ttl specifically while doing any update/write operation. Touch is also not needed. Do you see any issue with it?

Comment: There must be something not right with the policy, the way it is passed... I am not much familiar with the C client's API, but you should certainly be able to pass a policy with a different and set it. The default-ttl at the server config would be used only when the client passes in 0 as the ttl.

Answer (score 1):

The Aerospike server resets the record's ttl after every write operation (including touch).  If the desired ttl is not set for a write operation, the server default ttl is used.

The only way to accomplish your task is to set the same ttl on every write operation to that record. Set the ttl on the touch operation and then set the same ttl again on the map remove operation.